# Why can't python plot my function in this scenario?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, typeerror

I have the following Python function that calculates the probability of two people being born on the same day for a sample of k people :

```
def d(x):
  a=1-((factorial(365)/(factorial(365-x)))/365**x)
  return a
```

This works fine, the problem appears when i try to plot it, or use in array or lists:

```
t=np.arange(1,50)
plt.plot(t,d(t))
```

So i get that TypeError, and I don't know what i'm doing wrong honestly, because the function works fine by itself. How can I manage to work around this?

Comment: _So i get that TypeError_ Show us the whole error traceback.

Comment: Can it be a problem in factorial function?

Comment: Your problem is that your function `d` accepts a single value.  You're trying to pass an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
t=np.arange(1,50)
plt.plot(t,[d(i) for i in t])
```